# JavaScript наследование

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Есть такой код:

```
var a = [],
    b = [],
    c = [ 1, 2 ];

a = b = c;

a[2] = 3;

console.log(b);
```

По сути переменную **b** после присвоения ей значения мы не меняем. Но она меняется вместе с **a**.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В данном случае присваивание всего лишь записывает ссылку на массив [1, 2] в переменные "a" и "b".
Иными словами, каждая из переменных не содержит отдельный массив, а ссылается на один и тот же объект в памяти компьютера. 
Чтобы скопировать массив или его часть по значению (то есть записать в каждую из переменных уникальный массив), можно воспользоваться методом [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

P.S. К наследованию заданный вами вопрос не имеет никакого отношения.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже ответили выше, переменная b меняется вместе с a. Потому что при присваивании, создается ссылка указатель на значение переменной, а не новое значение.

Решить эту проблему так же, можно используя конструкцию JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()). Которая преобразует значение переменной в формат JSON, а потом обратно. (Ссылки и назойливые прототипы при этом теряются)

Пример:

```
var a = [],
    b = [],
    c = [ 1, 2 ];

a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
b = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(c));

a[2] = 3;

console.log(b);
```

И console.log(b) выведет: [1, 2]